# opencv can't make with vtk_on

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, vtk

im using ubuntu 14.04. and i have successfully installed vtk8.0.0.

Now i want to build opencv2.4.13.2 with vtk on.

And there is always errors, see belows.

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkGenericDataArray.h:72:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkAOSDataArrayTemplate.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkIntArray.h:33,
                 from /usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkCellTypes.h:42,
                 from /usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkPolyData.h:64,
                 from /usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkPolyDataAlgorithm.h:36,
                 from /usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkAppendPolyData.h:35,
                 from /home/suyz/Install/opencv/opencv-2.4.13.2/modules/viz/src/precomp.hpp:56,
                 from /home/suyz/Install/opencv/release/modules/viz/opencv_viz_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkGenericDataArrayLookupHelper.h:72:5: warning: identifier ‘nullptr’ is a keyword in C++11 [-Wc++0x-compat]
     : AssociatedArray{nullptr}, SortedArray(nullptr),
     ^
/usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkGenericDataArrayLookupHelper.h: In constructor ‘vtkGenericDataArrayLookupHelper<ArrayTypeT>::vtkGenericDataArrayLookupHelper()’:
/usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkGenericDataArrayLookupHelper.h:72:7: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
     : AssociatedArray{nullptr}, SortedArray(nullptr),
       ^
/usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkGenericDataArrayLookupHelper.h:72:23: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
     : AssociatedArray{nullptr}, SortedArray(nullptr),
                       ^
/usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkGenericDataArrayLookupHelper.h:73:5: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
     FirstValue{nullptr}, SortedArraySize{0}
     ^
/usr/local/include/vtk-8.0/vtkGenericDataArrayLookupHelper.h:73:26: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
     FirstValue{nullptr}, SortedArraySize{0}
                          ^
make[2]: *** [modules/viz/CMakeFiles/opencv_viz_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_viz_pch_dephelp.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/viz/CMakeFiles/opencv_viz_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

someone have a idea, how to solve this? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

VTK 8.0 and newer requires a c++11 compiler (`nullptr` is a C++11 feature). Did you install a prebuilt VTK? If so, check that you are using gcc 4.8 or newer and make sure your c++ flags include `-std=c++11` (you might try adding it to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` entry in `CMakeCache.txt` in your OpenCV build to see if the error goes away.

Comment: i builded vtk myself. So i think i have the c++ compiler. But it will not be used by default. How can i added it in CMakeCache.txt?  like this?               
//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING= "-std=c++11"

Comment: I think maybe this error is gone, but I have now trouble with CUDA.      [ 29%] Building NVCC (Device) object 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h(432): error: identifier "nullptr" is undefined.
It seems like, that CUDA8 is not compatible with c++11? Even if i active the  CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenCV's cuda support. Sorry.